# Changing the animation values via script in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've searched different sources but I couldn't find what I directly need. I use a maincamera in my scene and when some conditions are satisfied, I want my camera to animate to the point that I will get from an object which is in the scene. I tried to use Animation Curves but didn't work exactly how I wanted. So I thought of changing the values of the keys of the animation. Is there way that I can change keys and at the same time animation would animate how I want it to animate.

Comment: Sounds like you wouldn't want to use the animation system for such behavior ... we need more details for what and how exactly should happen but you are probably better using a **Coroutine** and stuff like `Vector3.Lerp`, `Quaternion.Slerp`, `Vector3.MoveTowards` etc

Answer (score -2):

I don't think animations are what you are looking for. I highly suggest you using a Tween asset or writing your own tweening library. Here is an example tweeting code that will move your object:

```
private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(Move(5));
}

private IEnumerator Move(float duration)
{
    var startPos = gameObject.transform.position;
    var targetPos = new Vector3(0, 10, 0);

    var timer = 0f;

    while (timer < duration)
    {
        transform.position = Mathf.Lerp(startPos, targetPos, timer / duration);
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }

    transform.position = targetPos;
}
```

This piece of code will take your `gameObject` and move it to the `targetPos` in `duration` seconds. What we do here is essentially called *linear interpolation*, which means that we change a value linearly from the start value to end value, and `timer / duration` is called *interpolation* value. The interpolation value must be between 0 and 1, where inputting 0 will give you the start value and 1 will give you the end value. You can smooth this interpolation value to get smoother movements.